# How do I trigger a hidden Quasar q-file input from an external q-btn?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework

I have a `q-file` element for selecting an image file, and a `q-img` element for displaying the image.

I don't like the `q-file` input style, so I want to hide it and trigger the image upload from an external `q-btn`.

But I don't know how to trigger the `q-file` from an external `q-btn`.

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
  
    const image = ref(null);
    const imageUrl = ref('');
    
    const handleUpload = () => {
      if (image.value) {
        imageUrl.value = URL.createObjectURL(image.value);
      }
    }
    
    const handleUploadBtnClick = () => {
      // Somehow trigger the hidden q-file selection window
    }
    
    return {
      image, imageUrl, handleUpload
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar)
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.4.13/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="q-app">
  <div>
    <q-file
      style="display: none"
      v-model="image"
      @update:model-value="handleUpload()"
   ></q-file>
  </div>
  <div>
    <q-btn
      type="button"
      label="Upload Photo"
      @click="handleUploadBtnClick"
   ></q-btn>
  </div>
  <div>
    <q-img
      :src="imageUrl"
      spinner-color="white"
      style="height: 140px; max-width: 150px"
    ></q-img>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.4.13/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just wrap both the input and button in a label, then the button will automatically trigger the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi @TinyTiger I was searching for the same with Script Setup and TypeScript and ended implementing this with Yusuf Kandemir help.

```js
<template>
  <q-card>
    <q-avatar
      color="red"
      v-on:click="selectFile()"
    >
      <q-img
        v-bind:src="img"
        v-bind:fit="'contain'"
        v-bind:ratio="1"
      />
    </q-avatar>

    <q-file
      ref="fileRef"
      v-model="fileModel"
      style="display: none"
      v-bind:max-files="1"
      accept="image/*"
      v-on:update:model-value="fileOnUpdate"
    />
  </q-card>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Ref, ref, onUnmounted } from 'vue'
import { QFile } from 'quasar'

const fileModel = ref<File>()
const fileRef = ref() as Ref<QFile>
const img = ref<string>()

function selectFile() {
  fileRef.value.pickFiles()
}

function fileOnUpdate(selectedFile: File) {
  if (img.value) {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(img.value)
  }
  img.value = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile)
}

onUnmounted(() => {
  if (img.value) {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(img.value)
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create `ref` to `q-file` , then from `q-btn` call it with `file.value.pickFiles()`

```js
const { ref, onMounted } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
  
    const image = ref(null);
    const imageUrl = ref('');
    const file = ref(null)
    
    const handleUpload = () => {
      if (image.value) {
        imageUrl.value = URL.createObjectURL(image.value);
      }
    }
    
    const handleUploadBtnClick = () => {
      file.value.pickFiles()
    }
    
    return {
      image, imageUrl, handleUpload, handleUploadBtnClick, file
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar)
app.mount('#q-app')
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.4.13/dist/quasar.prod.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div id="q-app">
  <div>
    <q-file
      style="display: none"
      v-model="image"
      @update:model-value="handleUpload"
      ref="file"
   ></q-file>
  </div>
  <div>
    <q-btn
      type="button"
      label="Upload Photo"
      @click="handleUploadBtnClick"
   ></q-btn>
  </div>
  <div>
    <q-img
      :src="imageUrl"
      spinner-color="white"
      style="height: 140px; max-width: 150px"
    ></q-img>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quasar@2.4.13/dist/quasar.umd.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works, but I'm getting EsLint errors on `file.value.pickFiles()` saying `Unsafe call of an 'any' typed value.` and `Property 'pickFiles' does not exist on type 'never'.`. I tried to fix it by typing the template ref like so `const file: Ref<HTMLDivElement | null> = ref(null);`.  That did not work. Now I am getting `Unsafe call of an 'any' typed value.` and `Property 'pickFiles' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'.` errors. It seems I need to type the q-file template ref correctly, but I don't know how. Any ideas? I do not want to disable the EsLint errors, but instead fix them.

Comment: @TinyTiger sorry mate, sadly I don't know typescript :(